# shell script error : [: : integer expression expected

Tags: java, shell

i am trying to trigger an email alert based on the java script output but i am getting an error like below in the shell script,

```
 script.sh: line 22: [: : integer expression expected

Below is my shell script format,

 out="$(java -jar /waitrose/scripts/OF/BOBIErrorAutomation/BOBIAutomation.jar 
 2>&1)"
 if [ "$out" -gt 0 ]
 then
 mail -s "script did not completed successfully" $mailid_list
 exit 0
 fi
```

Below is the sample error returned by the java program :

```
The error was: com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.a.<init>(a.java:174) 174
com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.b.a(b.java:1745) 1745
com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.p.<init>(p.java:934) 934
```

Can anyone tell me how to capture the output from the java program and trigger the mail in shell ?

Answer (score 0):

are you not comparing the output of your java program which in the case where it crashes, most likely going to be a string of some sort, against (-gt greater than) an integer? the comparator expects a whole number, not a crash message from java.

EDIT: ill elaborate, perhaps it would be better to test if $out is an integer first, if your jar only outputs integers if it runs correctly:

```
if ! [[ "$out" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
```

then use this to trigger your mail, and else to normal functionality.

Comment: please wait until you get enough reputation to comment. Answers are meant to answer the question, not seek clarification on it.